# Coded UI - Cross browser issue. Not able to identify controls on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cross-browser, coded-ui-tests

I have a web application hosted on http://localhost/MyWebApplication. And I am using Coded UI as a tool to perform UI Automation on the application

I have to carry out concurrency kind of scenaios where in two different admin users (say user1 & user2) login to http://localhost/MyWebApplication. When user1 performs any operation like edit or delete the same should be reflected on data for  user2

To achieve this, I am logging into MyWebAppliction on IE browser as user1 & Chrome browser as user2. And I am able to launch and login to IE & Chrome as user1 & user2 respectively.

Now after I perform some edit, delete operation on user1 in IE, I need to go back & check if it is reflected in user2 in chrome. And I need to do Vise-versa as well (i.e Chrome to IE)

To switch between the browsers, I have writtent below method to bring the required browser (IE or chrome) to foreground

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    public void SwitchBrowserForMyWebApp(string browserName)
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Process[] p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(browserName).Where(x => x.MainWindowTitle.Contains("My Web Application")).ToArray();

        if (p.Length > 0)
        {
            SetForegroundWindow(p[0].MainWindowHandle); // bring the desired browser to the front
        }

       // ========== Till here it works fine & brings the required browser to the front.

        BrowserWindow curWindow;

        if (browserName == "iexplore")
        {
            BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "IE";
        }

        else
        {
            BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = browserName;
            Process browserProcess = p[0];

             BrowserWindow bwp = BrowserWindow.FromProcess(p[0]);    // Here it gives null exception - Object not set to instance of an object
            //BrowserWindow.Locate("My Web Application - Google Chrome");             

        }

    }
```

Problem I am facing here is, If i bring IE to foreground, then I am able to access controls and perform edit or update

But if I bring chrome to foreground, then I am unable to access any of the controls on chrome.

I tried setting CurrentBrowser as "Chrome", used BrowserWindow.Locate("My Web Application - Google Chrome"), Also used BrowserWindow.FromProcess(p[0]);

Not able to find what is the issue. I am using IE 11 & Chrome version: 47.0.2526.111 m

Can any one let me know if I am missing anything. Or any work around to resolve this issue

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but Setting the "CurrentBrowser" Property does not switch browsers. This property has to be set before you call the Browser.Launch() Method to initialize the browser driver u use. It's defaulted to IE. U will have to use two different Browser Instance and use the one need. May be something like this,

```
public static BrowserWindow CurrentBrowser= null, Chrome = null, IE = null; 

IE = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri("http:\\urAppURLHere.COM"));

BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "Chrome"
Chrome = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri("http:\\urAppURLHere.COM"));

CurrentBrowser = GetMeTheBrowserIWant("Chrome");


public static BrowserWindow GetMeTheBrowserIWant(string BrowserType)
{
    if(BrowserType.ToUpper().Equals("CHROME")
    {
       return Chrome;
    } 
      if(BrowserType.ToUpper().Equals("IE")
    {
       return IE;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are Switching the Browser, but the Test Object u identified is still instantiated with Chrome. 
You will have to re identify the Test Object using IE Again.

Something like,

```
GmailLogOnButton = new HtmlControl(GetMeTheBrowserIWant("IE"));
GmailLogOnButton.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.Id, "signIn");
```

Coded Ui framework is not developed considering Concurrent execution of **Same Steps**. So when you try concurrency tests, u will end up doing additional steps.

You, may also consider using Threading, but it may create difficulties in how u sync your tests!!